# Making components fill maximum whitespace depending on changing sizes

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, layout

I'm developing a UI in C# in Visual Studio 2012 using Windows Forms, and I'm trying to make it such that the components in my form fill all the whitespace possible. The thing is, the user should be able to resize these components at will. A FlowLayoutPanel won't work, because if a component is too small or too big, there will be too much whitespace in its row. A TableLayoutPanel, while allowing for components to span columns and rows, is simply unfeasible as far as I can tell. So I'm stuck for a solution.

For an idea of what I'm looking for, check out this site: http://wearethelittleones.tumblr.com/
or
http://ville-noire.com/

Of course, in both cases, the images have been resized to make the layout look better -- the layout is effectively just a vertical FlowLayout. But I hope I get my point across; It should effectively be like a FlowLayout that works both vertically and horizontally. It's kind of like if you were arranging tiles of different sizes, starting from the top left, trying to minimize the distance from the top left, trying to be as efficient as possible with regards to space wasted.

In any case, I think that's enough description. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a combination of a splitContainer and flowlayoutpanel. You can fiddle with the margins to change the "white space".